# Spin other than integer and half-integer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I was looking at the [Quantum Atlas entry for Spin](https://quantumatlas.umd.edu/entry/Spin) which had a standard explanation

> Like many things in the quantum world, spin is quantized, which means
>   that the spin of a particle is limited to particular values—0, 1/2, 1
>   and 3/2 are fine, but 1.349 is not. The allowed values separate every
>   particle in the universe into two categories, depending on whether
>   their spin is an integer like 1 or a half-integer like 1/2. You’re
>   either a boson or a fermion. There are no other options.

with a tantalizing note:

> This is almost true. In certain circumstances it's possible for
>   particles to emerge with other spin values, but they are a special
>   case.

Can anyone elaborate? Under what circumstances would a particle have a spin value other than an integer or half-integer? What kind of particle would it be, and what kinds of spin values are possible? (Presumably this requires interpreting the terms suitably, so it may be a quasiparticle or something else not quite fitting the standard definitions such that it can evade impossibility results.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon

Comment: Maybe you are referring to this (https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~mtamash/f689_mecquant_i/prl49_957.pdf) but I am not able to give you a real answer